# Android equivalent to UIImageViews in a UIView in a UIScrollView

Tags: android, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a nice view in iOS and want to do the same in android, but couldn't find out how.

Basically it's one big background image and several smaller images overlayed and the whole needs to be zoomed at the same time, imagine for example a map with cars on it.

I tried working with a WebView, but couldn't configure it right, so I'm looking for a better solution. And I need the pinch zooming feature, the Webview -/+ was not really helpful.

Working code would be nice too, cause most examples I tried didn't work as expected.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: 5 years ago? don‘t even remember which project this was on, but i think the quick and dirty solution was drawing backround and overlays in a new image. if i had to try it now i would probably arrange them all in a relativelayout/framelayout and then try to add the zooming

Answer (score -1):

Would be util put you ImageViews in a GridView?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Comment: Sorry, this will not work for me because the images need to overlap, I've updated my question.